# PyGame image save colors distorted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I have implemented the following screenshot functionality into my game just to log progress and stuff like that. This is my code:

```
pygame.image.save(screen, save_file)
```

Pretty basic. I recently upgraded to python 3.3 and have since been having the issue of distorted colors using this function. Here is what I mean:

Distorted Color:
[image: Distorted screen shot]

So it looks quite nice, but it isn't how it supposed to be. This is the actual image:

[image: Actual Image]

Is this a known issue or is it just me? Are there any fixes to it or is it just a broken function at the moment. I am using pygame 1.9.2pre and I am assuming it is just a bug with the pre release but I was having issues using any other versions of pygame with python 3.3.

Comment: The distorted image is quite cool—I'd keep it.

Comment: I agree haha. It would be nice to somehow have this affect on the actual game or perhaps replicate it somehow for other types of screenshots but it isn't what I want for general screenshotting ^_^

Comment: It looks like your red and green channels got swapped, although I don't know why. As a last resort, you can save the distorted image, re-swap the channels, and you'll get the actual image data. Of course, it would be preferable to not get distorted data in the first place.

Comment: what format are you saving as? PNG? Does the problem persist if you use BMP? What about if you use lowercase instead of uppercase, or vice versa? (a strange question, I know, but [some users](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save) report that different casing changes the behavior of `save`)

Comment: Changing the file type to BMP worked perfectly. Thankyou, I can't believe I hadn't thought of that. If you want to make this an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as it worked. Although I would like to know why it doesn't work for PNG format.

Comment: I think it's [this bug](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/39/pygame-191release-endian-problem-saving-an).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Some users](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save) have reported difficulty with saving images as pngs:

> I only get .tga files even when I specify .png.  Very frustrating.
>
> If you use .PNG (uppercase), it will result in an invalid file (at least on my win32).  Use .png (lowercase) instead.
>
> PNG does not seem to work, I am able to get a preview of it in Thunar, but everywhere else It says that it is not a valid PNG.

Saving in a different format may be helpful. For example, BMP is a simple format, so it's unlikely that Pygame's implementation will be buggy.

If you really want to save as PNG, you can reverse the distortion by swapping the red channel with the green one. This is fairly easy. For example, using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("screenshot.png")
width, height = im.size

pix = im.load()
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        r,g,b = pix[i,j]
        pix[i,j] = (g,r,b)

im.save("output.png")
```

Or you can save as BMP and convert to PNG after the fact:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("screenshot.bmp")
im.save("screenshot.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

for future reference, this trick worked for me:

```
from PIL import Image
imgdata = pygame.surfarray.array3d(screen).transpose([1,0,2])[:,:,::-1]
Image.fromarray(imgdata).save('output.png')
```